# Что означает \ в строке JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Что означает "\" в строке JavaScript перед символами? И как его правильно использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это экранирование.

```js
console.log('Без экрана \n'); 
console.log('Экранируем \\n');
```

Comment: То есть, один слеш убирает следующий символ, а два - оставляют?

Comment: @НовиковМаксим Есть так скажем спецсимволы, управляющие символы 

`\n, \b, обыкновенные кавычки " " , одинарные ' '`

Если вы скажем, напишете подобное : `console.log (' I'm ')` ; получите синтаксическую ошибку. Потому-что текст строки должен быть обёрнут в кавычки одинарные или двойные. В данном случае у нас 3 кавычки и та что внутри I'm должна быть экранирована, поэтому напишем так `console.log (' I\'m ')` . Почитайте вообщем про экранирование.

Comment: @EVG предлагаю поменять `\n` на `\t` или что-нибудь другое более наглядное, а то автор работы примера не понял)

Comment: Я слышал, что если ставить \ перед каким - либо символом, то браузер его  игнорирует

Comment: @НовиковМаксим да грубо говоря так. Хотите один \ чтоб отображался - то ставите \\ . Также есть ряд спецсимволом, перенос строки `\n`, возврат каретки и.т.д , если вы хотите чтоб вывелось `\n` то пишете `\\n`, если хотите перенос строки, то ставите спец.символ `\n` который отображаться не будет в встроке. Тоесть спецсимволы типа `\n`,`\t` воспринимается интерпритатор как один символ, который в простонародье называют спецсимволом.